# Multiple submit buttons. One formtype

Tags: file-upload, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a `ProfileType` form with a user picture field. Is it possible to build two different forms out of the same type and entity on the same page? I want the user to be able to upload an avatar separately by ajax, which I have no problem with, but in the event of no js, I want accessibility and the ability to just use good old php, but in separate forms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to create two forms with two different names:

```
$formFactory = $this->container->get('form.factory');
$form1 = $formFactory->createNamed(new MyType(), 'form1', $object);
$form2 = $formFactory->createNamed(new MyType(), 'form2', $object);

if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
    if ($request->request->has('form1')) {
        $form1->bindRequest($request);
        ...
    }

    if ($request->request->has('form2')) {
        $form2->bindRequest($request);
        ...
    }
}
```